# How to Change JupyterLab Menu ICON

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Hi there I was wondering here if anyone knew how to change the icon in the menu of the JupyterLab. I've been creating a docker image that has a custom environment and have been able to change all the icons except for this one. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!